# How do I copy an NSManagedObject to pass to a new viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I would like to pass a copy of an NSManagedObject to a new viewController. How would I make a copy of the object?

```
Store *store = [self.stores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //stores in an array of stores

StoreDetailViewController *v = [[StoreDetailViewController alloc] initWithText:@"" forStore:store];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
[v release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send a `NSManagedObject` the `copy` message as it does not conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: I keep receiving '-[Store copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance using this method.